# Confused about "How could I have done this?"

Tags: sentence-construction, present-perfect

This comes up while I am watching westworld. 
There is one scene in it. Teddy did some horrible things without consciousness. Then he backed to normal and asked Delores "How could I have done that?" 
Now I'm confused about this. As I learned from the grammar book, "could have done" is only used in unreal condition in the past or making a guess in the past. In this case, Teddy had already done the horrible things so the "unreal condition" explanation may not work. He also already knew the result so it's not like a guess either. Why didn't he say "How had I done that"? I'm puzzled here. Could anyone help share some insights on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

He is separating himself from the action. He is admitting he did the action but also admitting it was wrong. He is stating disbelief that he would ever have done the thing he did. **Could** means 'possibly' in this usage.

Answer (score 0):

Can/could, present and past tense, no IF clause or whether or other idea.

How **could I have done*** that? is the past tense of: How **can I do** that?

How **can you say** she is rich [right now, present]? How **could you say** she was rich [yesterday]? Or: How **could you have said** she was rich?

Summary: present tense: can, simple past: could + verb, past perfect: could have + participle.

That is a difference usage than:
**He could have gone, if he had had the mone**y. **There is your unreal condition**.

**These are two separate uses of CAN versus COULD or COULD + verb and COULD HAVE + participle**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is that an oral English usage which can not be found in grammar book? Is that common in US nowadays?

Comment: @zhe It has nothing at all to do with American usage or spoken English, except I have spoken English examples. It's the same in all varieties of English. In written English, the tenses are CAN (present), COULD (simple past) COULD HAVE + past particle. Could have + past participle usually implies an unreal condition but not always: More examples: //How could the politicians have done this to their constituents?// You see?

Comment: They did do it (whatever) so, in fact, there is no unreal condition. //What possibly could have happened to those kids? It's midnight.//  //The voters could have elected him because they are stupid.// [See? past tense of actual event].

Comment: @ Lambie  Take the last one for example. The unreal conditon usage: I know the result he isn't the president. I can say "The voters could have elected him". It means The voters had the ability to elect him to a president but voters didn't elect him. The guess in the past usage: I don't know the result if he is the president now. I say "The voters could have elected him". It means I only make a guess if the voters elected him.

Comment: Can I understand your explanation like this: I know the result he is the president. I can still say "The voters could have elected him because they are stupid" which also equals "The voters could elect him because they are stupid". Is this a third usage different from the two above? Am I understanding that right?

Comment: No, the voters could have elected him (but they did not) does not equal The voters could elect him. The voters could elect him because they are stupid, contains a future idea. Sorry, I forgot that one. :)

Comment: @ Lambie  Except the equal part, do you think my understanding your explanation is correct?

Comment: @zhe I do not have a crystal ball. :) [I am not a foretune teller].

Comment: @ Lambie Sorry, I didn't get it. Maybe I didn't explain my idea quite well. I'll make it like this. So when you know someone is the president, you can't use this expression to others 'How could he have become the president?' but you can use 'how could he become the president?' Am I right? Looking forward to your replies. I'm so confused on this. Thanks.

Comment: @zhe The answer is no, you CAN use both :) /How could he have become president?/ and /How could he become president/ [let's leave the /the/ out of it for now] are both correct in English. You need to work on understanding the timeline for verbs in English (I know that does not exist in Chinese) and therefore can be very confusing. Here is a well-done timeline for  verbs in English: http://www.englishlessonsbrighton.co.uk/all-english-tenses-timeline-infographic/ Let me know if this has helped you. :)

Comment: @ Lambie Thanks a lot.:) It helped. Now I'm much clear.  Guess 'How could he have become president?' is just a past perfect usage, so it should equal to 'How could he become president?'. I'm too obsessed with the unreal condition and guess condition. Sorry to trouble you with a new one. With my understanding, I made up another example trying to change the question sentence to declarative sentence. 'I could've drunk ten bottles of beer when I was young.' and 'I could drink ten bottles of beer when I was young'. Are these two equaled? I'm hoping your help on this. Thanks.

Comment: **could** as the past tense of **can** isn't "oral english": just look in a dictionary and you will find it. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/could

Comment: @zhe Please post a separate question.

Comment: @JavaLatte , **could** as the past tense of **can** totally *is* "oral English", and "I could drink that much when I was young." is a great example of it. "I can do it" : "I could do it" = "I am able to do it" : "I was able to do it."

Comment: @zhe I really, really hate these types of questions. If I could remove my answer completely, and not just have it "fade out", I would. Your are confusing various uses such as: **can** (present); **could** (past tense); **can (+ a verb)** (present tense of the modal); **could (+ plus a verb)**,  (simple past tense of the modal or a conditional); **could have (past participle of verb)**, past conditional of can go. The ultimate goal: sorting out all those uses, among others.

Comment: @LorelC. My comment is a response to zhe's first comment: note the use of quote marks round "oral english". What perhaps I should have said is ... could as the past tense of can isn't **just** "oral english"...